# BioNLP stanford - tokenization

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I try to tokenize a biomedical text so I decided to use http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/eventparser.shtml. I used the stand-alone program RunBioNLPTokenizer that does what I want.

Now, I want to create my own program that uses Stanford libraries. So, I read the code from RunBioNLPTokenizer describing below.

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.bionlp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.GenericDataSetReader;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.msteventextractor.DataSet;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.msteventextractor.EpigeneticsDataSet;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.msteventextractor.GENIA11DataSet;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.msteventextractor.InfectiousDiseasesDataSet;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils;

/**
 * Standalone program to run our BioNLP tokenizer and save its output
 */
public class RunBioNLPTokenizer extends GenericDataSetReader {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties(args);
    String basePath = props.getProperty("base.directory", "/u/nlp/data/bioNLP/2011/originals/");

    DataSet dataset = new GENIA11DataSet();
    dataset.getFilesystemInformation().setTokenizer("stanford");
    runTokenizerForDirectory(dataset, basePath + "genia/training");
    runTokenizerForDirectory(dataset, basePath + "genia/development");
    runTokenizerForDirectory(dataset, basePath + "genia/testing");

    dataset = new EpigeneticsDataSet();
    dataset.getFilesystemInformation().setTokenizer("stanford");
    runTokenizerForDirectory(dataset, basePath + "epi/training");
    runTokenizerForDirectory(dataset, basePath + "epi/development");
    runTokenizerForDirectory(dataset, basePath + "epi/testing");

    dataset = new InfectiousDiseasesDataSet();
    dataset.getFilesystemInformation().setTokenizer("stanford");
    runTokenizerForDirectory(dataset, basePath + "infect/training");
    runTokenizerForDirectory(dataset, basePath + "infect/development");
    runTokenizerForDirectory(dataset, basePath + "infect/testing");
  }

  private static void runTokenizerForDirectory(DataSet dataset, String path) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Input directory: " + path);
    BioNLPFormatReader reader = new BioNLPFormatReader();    
    for (File rawFile : reader.getRawFiles(path)) {
      System.out.println("Input filename: " + rawFile.getName());
      String rawText = IOUtils.slurpFile(rawFile);

      String docId = rawFile.getName().replace("." + BioNLPFormatReader.TEXT_EXTENSION, "");
      String parentPath = rawFile.getParent();

      runTokenizer(dataset.getFilesystemInformation().getTokenizedFilename(parentPath, docId), rawText);
    }
  }

  private static void runTokenizer(String tokenizedFilename, String text) {
    System.out.println("Tokenized filename: " + tokenizedFilename);
    Collection<String> sentences = BioNLPFormatReader.splitSentences(text);

    PrintStream os = null;
    try {
      os = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(tokenizedFilename));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("ERROR: cannot save online tokenization to " + tokenizedFilename);
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }

    for (String sentence : sentences) {
      BioNLPFormatReader.BioNLPTokenizer tokenizer = new BioNLPFormatReader.BioNLPTokenizer(sentence);
      List<CoreLabel> tokens = tokenizer.tokenize();
      for (CoreLabel l : tokens) {
        os.print(l.word() + " ");
      }
      os.println();
    }
    os.close();
  }
}
```

I wrote the below code. I achieved to split the text into sentences but I can't use the BioNLPTokenizer as it is used in RunBioNLPTokenizer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  // TODO code application logic here
  Collection<String> c =BioNLPFormatReader.splitSentences("..");
  for (String sentence : c) {
    System.out.println(sentence);
    BioNLPFormatReader.BioNLPTokenizer x = BioNLPFormatReader.BioNLPTokenizer(sentence);
  }
}
```

I took this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.bionlp.BioNLPFormatReader.BioNLPTokenizer has protected access in edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.domains.bionlp.BioNLPFormatReader

My question is. How can I tokenize a biomedical sentence according to Stanford libraries without using RunBioNLPTokenizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we made `BioNLPTokenizer` a `protected` inner class, so you'd need to edit the source and change its access to `public`.

Note that `BioNLPTokenizer` may not be the most general purpose biomedical sentence tokenzier -- I would spot check the output to make sure it is reasonable. We developed it heavily against the BioNLP 2009/2011 shared tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the problem (i think). I did my class to extend the BioNLPFormatReader. This worked for me. I have already read that this is in beta version. Is there any tokenizer for biomedical text in your library?

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a workaround. I would probably say "mostly unmaintained" rather than "beta" as Mihai and myself are no longer at Stanford :) Which library are you referring to?

Comment: Well, I mean the Stanford CoreNLP library. But, if you know anything else about tokenization in biomedicine, I'll appreciate it.  Thank you in advance :)

Comment: See the Toolkits section in this paper (mostly about sentence boundary detection, but also has some on tokenization): https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5001746/